# Declaring and modifying Static array of structure -CPP

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I have defined in header file a structure and it's array like this:

```
struct
{
int a;
 char* b;
 } S_element, s_array*;

static s_array my_data[3] = {1,"first", 2, "second", 3, "third"     };
```

In the source code I include such a header and access this array. I am  trying to change the value of the string variable b inside the structure of an array element , but the program is crashing at this point, when I try to change the value of struct member - b.

Sorry for the syntax errors in this question code. I have access only to my mobile phone as of now.

I am not sure of the concepts involving static members, and initializing array in this way without curly braces for individual struct elements.

Comment: C or C++? Choose one programming language, please!

Answer (score 1):

writing `struct{...}a;` is the same as `struct name{...}; name a;`

you can't write `static s_array my_data[3]` because `s_array` is  struct, not a type.

also, this is not the way to restart a struct array.

change to:

```
typedef struct{

int a;

 char* b;

 } S_element, *s_array;

static S_element my_data[3] = {{1,"first"}, {2, "second"}, {3, "third"}};
```

see that I changed to S_element because s_array is a pointer, not a struct.

also, don't use `static` in headers, only in functions.

Comment: _because s_array is struct, not a type_ ... What? O.o

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problems in my code. Now  inside a function, I am looping through each array element and trying to reassign a different value for the struct members. But the program crashes when I do that. Are the values in static member read-only?

Comment: _because s_array is struct, not a type_ means that you can't write:                  `struct{...} a; a b;`